# use LDoc to generate document for whole lua project with index page

Tags: lua, luadoc

I want to generate documentation for my `lua` project 
but with `Ldoc` i generate `docs` for each single `lua` file and the output file every time overwrite the `index.html` file .

So my question is how i can generate generate documentation for the whole project with index page that has link to the all pages.

I tried to do that with see tag but i don't know if i can use it to reference to another file not another part in the document

I used this:

```
ldoc.lua.bat pathtomyproject/filename.lua
```

The output is the default path `myluainstallationpath/doc/index.html`.

Comment: i didn't find any command to do that i tried powershell script to read alla files but doesn't work in LDoc case because it overwrite same always

Comment: ldoc.lua.bat pathtomyproject/filename.lua

Comment: the output is the default path myluainstallationpath/doc/index.html

Comment: Please add your config file to your post (*not* in a comment)

Comment: thx schollii but i want to know is there any way to generate doc for whole project in ldoc like an attribute or something i have read all the documentation and i didnt find any thing talking about that

Comment: So you have multiple Lua files in `pathtomyproject`, right?

Comment: yes i have multiple files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `ldoc.lua.bat pathtomyproject` instead. This will generate the docs for all the files in `pathtomyproject` and will generate an index.html that links to each file used in that folder..

Comment: Hm, I try something similar but ldoc does not generate anything if I pass the root directory ([see](https://github.com/stevedonovan/LDoc/issues/258)). Any idea what I might do wrong?